# Canvas not showing even though the code is there

Tags: javascript, magic-mirror

I am trying to show a [Gauge](https://canvas-gauges.com/) on my Magic Mirror Dashboard in my module programmatically.

The below is a sample of my code:

```
    var indoorGauge = document.createElement('canvas');
    indoorGauge.id = 'indoorGauge';
    ...
    indoorGauge.setAttribute('data-animation-target','plate');  
    indoorPressure.appendChild(indoorGauge);        
    insideTele.appendChild(indoorPressure);
    wrapper.appendChild(insideTele);
```

The gauge doesn't show or render. What I'm finding odd is that when I inspect element, the canvas is all there and it works, because when I cut out the element and re-paste it, it will show up and work perfectly!

[image]

If I 'cut' and 'paste' the above canvas element, the gauge will show just fine.

[image]

Comment: Complete the code

Comment: What do you mean complete the code? The ellipsis just denotes the extra attributes.

Comment: Where is the wrapper?

Comment: The wrapper is part of the magic-mirror module. Any element inside it will show fine. Only the canvas doesn't render. I'm attaching some pics to original post

Comment: At the first, don't use append. create a canvas element in HTML code and give it id to your `gauge`, it's work?

Comment: i dont understand. I'm creating the canvas element in html no? '    var indoorGauge = document.createElement('canvas');'

Comment: Could you make a minimal, reproducible example? It's hard to tell what's going on otherwise :/

Comment: Check this document: https://canvas-gauges.com/documentation/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://canvas-gauges.com/documentation/user-guide/), you should be using their API if you want to load a gauge with Javascript.

```js
const indoorGauge = document.createElement('canvas');

indoorGauge.id = "indoorGauge"
document.body.appendChild(indoorGauge);

new LinearGauge({
  renderTo: 'indoorGauge'
}).draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-gauges@2.1.7/gauge.min.js"></script>
```

I would imagine that because you are appending the canvas with Javascript, but not using the gauge API that's why you're seeing issues with the script not picking up your dynamically created canvas element the first time you add it